# Function call after AJAX request does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, return

I have a function where the alert is working:

```
function RequestNext() {

    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            MyCard = GetCard(xhr.responseText);
            **alert(MyCard.GetNo());**
            return MyCard;
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "../../HttpRequest_Next.php" , true);

    xhr.send(null);                                             
}
```

Then I have this other function where the first one gets called and the same alert does not work:

```
function Start(){

    var MyCard = RequestNext();

    alert("Patience.js");
    **alert(MyCard.GetNo());**
    alert("test2");
    //alert(Card.GetKind());
    //WriteCard(Card);
    alert("test3");
}
```

For information, those functions are in 2 files.

Comment: This is the gotcha of asynchronous programming. This is such a common SO question I'd like to find a really nice blog post that covers it and link people to it. So far not finding one.

Comment: Your _RequestNext()_ function doesn't have a _return_ statement. Only your inner anonymous function has a _return_. So even ignoring the async issue this code wouldn't work.

Comment: I understand both comment but I don't see how I can make this work. Is there a way to wait for Ajax to complete before processing the rest of my code?

Comment: I'd probably use a callback function that would be called from the point where you currently have the _return_ statement. (Unfortunately I'm writing this comment on my phone, where it is too hard to enter actual code; I'll use my laptop to type something up for you tonight (Australian time) if you haven't got another answer by then.)

Comment: Thanks a lot I already got a exemple of your saying. That is a great idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where a callback is a great idea.  Basically you pass a function as an argument, so that you can then run that function when the ajax (which is asyncronous) completes.  The syntax here may be slightly off, but you could do something like:

```
function RequestNext(callback) {

  var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
        MyCard = GetCard(xhr.responseText);
        **alert(MyCard.GetNo());**
        if (typeof callback=='undefined') return MyCard;
        else {
          return callback.call(MyCard);
        }
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", "../../HttpRequest_Next.php" , true);

  xhr.send(null);                                             
}
function Start(){
  var MyCard = RequestNext(function() {
      alert("Patience.js");
      alert(this.GetNo());
      alert("test2");
      //alert(this.GetKind());
      //WriteCard(this);
      alert("test3");
      return this;
  });
}
```